# $f,g:[0,1]→R$ be $2$ continuous functions such that $f(x)g(x)≥4x^{2}$, for all $x∈[0,1]$. Prove that $|\int_{0}^1f(x)dx|≥1$ or $|\int_{0}^1g(x)dx|> 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f,g:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb R$ be two continuous functions such that $f(x)g(x)\ge4x^{2}$, for all $x\in[0,1]$ . Prove that $|\int_{0}^1f(x)dx|\ge1$ or $|\int_{0}^1g(x)dx|\ge1$

My approach:

Since $f(x)g(x) > 4x^{2},\,\,\,
\int_{0}^1f(x)g(x)dx>\frac{4}{3}$

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality

$\int_{0}^1f(x)^{2}dx\cdot\int_{0}^1g(x)^{2}dx>\frac{16}{9}>1$

So $\int_{0}^1f(x)^{2}dx>1\text{ or }\int_{0}^1g(x)^{2}dx>1$

After this I cant proceed.

Comment: Solution in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3675602. Also on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1721045p11132041

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(x)g(x)\geq4x^2\implies \sqrt{f(x)g(x)}\geq 2x.$$
Then, conclude as you did.

Comment: and so ? $f$ and $g$ has anyway the same sign and is always the same on $[0,1]$... @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because of $f(x)g(x)\geq 4x^2$ and $f$ and $g$ are continuous we have $f(x)\geq 0$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ or vice versa.

Assume both functions are nonegative. Suppose $|\int_{0}^1f(x)dx|<1$ and  $|\int_{0}^1g(x)dx|<1$. Then we have by triangle inequality $$ |\int_{0}^14xdx|\leq |\int_{0}^12\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}dx|\leq |\int_{0}^1(f(x)+ g(x))dx|<2$$

So we get $2<2$ a contradiction.

If both are negative replace $f,g$ with $-f$ respectively $-g$.